# Repairing rusted-out parking brake bracket on 2001 Ford F150

Tags: ford, emergency-brakes

I'd like to repair the parking/emergency brake on a 2001 Ford F-150 XLT pickup.  The front bracket has failed due to body rust.  No local body shop is interested in performing the repair, and with a failed parking/emergency brake the vehicle will fail state inspection.

Except for the rusted-out body parts, the truck is in excellent condition and has a lot of life left in it, so repairing the truck is my strongly-preferred solution.  And as a non-expert in motor vehicles I'm pretty much lost in doing anything that isn't step-by-step from a Chilton manual.

Unfortunately, I can't locate any online resources that provide step-by-step repair instructions that I can handle here.  Everything I've found is for doing things like replacing an emergency brake cable (or brake pads or ...) and not how to repair an emergency brake that's had its mounting bracket fall off because of a rusted-out body.

This is an image of the area underneath the driver's side of the cab:

[image]

This is another view:

[image]

Comment: looks like you will be learning to cut metal to shape and weld... good luck.

Comment: Cut a good one from a junk vehicle and weld it to your tuck.

Answer (score 1):

ummm...if you admit you're not a "car guy," these suggestions are like "if you have a toothache, become a dentist!" LOL ;-)
Maybe you're looking for a good truck restoration guy?

Comment: Perhaps from the tone of the post the OP is looking to learn. Suggesting "take it to a professional" has already been covered by the post.